# Devextreme vue multiline toolbar

Tags: vuejs2, datagrid, toolbar, devextreme

How to configure multiline toolbar in devextreme-vue datagrid?

I have tried customizing tool bar using **onToolbarPreparing** method.

Here is my code -

```
<dx-data-grid :allow-column-reordering="true"
                      :allow-column-resizing="true"
                      :columns="config.columns"
                      :data-source="obligations"
                      :focused-row-enabled="true"
                      :focused-row-key.sync="focusedRowKey"
                      :onInitNewRow="onInitNewRow"
                      :onOptionChanged="change"
                      :onRowInserted="onRowInserted"
                      :onRowInserting="onRowInserting"
                      :onRowRemoved="onRowRemoved"
                      :onRowRemoving="onRowRemoving"
                      :onRowUpdated="onRowUpdated"
                      :onRowUpdating="onRowUpdating"
                      :ref="ref"
                      :rowAlternationEnabled="true"
                      :show-borders="true"
                      @focused-row-changed="onFocusRowChanged"
                      @toolbar-preparing="onToolbarPreparing($event)"
                      class="dx-datagrid-h-200"
                      key-expr="entityId">
            <dx-column-fixing :enabled="true"/>
            <dx-filter-row :apply-filter="currentFilter"
                           :visible="showFilterRow==='Yes'"/>
            <dx-header-filter :visible="showHeaderFilter"/>
            <dx-editing :allow-adding="allowEditing"
                        :allow-deleting="allowEditing"
                        :allow-updating="allowEditing"
                        :fixed="true"
                        :form="form"
                        :mode="mode"
                        :use-icons="true"
                        start-edit-action="click"/>
            <dx-export :allow-export-selected-data="true"
                       :enabled="true"
                       file-name="Obligations"/>
            <dx-group-panel :visible="true"/>
            <dx-grouping :auto-expand-all="autoExpandAll"/>
            <dx-sorting mode="multiple"/>
            <dx-selection :select-all-mode="selectionMode"
                          mode="multiple"
                          show-check-boxes-mode="always"/>
            <dx-state-storing :custom-load="customLoad"
                              :custom-save="customSave"
                              :enabled="true"
                              type="custom"/>
            <dx-paging :enabled="true" :page-count="12"
                       :page-index="config.pageIndex"
                       :page-size="config.pageSize"/>
            <dx-pager :allowed-page-sizes="config.allowedPageSizes"
                      :show-info="true"
                      :show-navigation-buttons="true"
                      :show-page-size-selector="true"
                      :visible="true"/>
            <dx-column-chooser :allow-search="true"
                               :enabled="true"
                               empty-panel-text="Test"
                               mode="select"
                               title="Column Settings"/>
        </dx-data-grid>
```

And:

```
  onToolbarPreparing(e) {
                    e.toolbarOptions.items.push(
                    {
                        location: 'after',
                        widget: 'dxDropDownButton',
                        options: {
                            displayExpr: 'name',
                            keyExpr: 'value',
                            selectedItemKey: this.mode,
                            width: 100,
                            stylingMode: 'outlined',
                            useSelectMode: true,
                            onSelectionChanged: (e) => {
                                this.mode = e.item.value;
                            },
                            items: [
                                {value: 'batch', name: 'Batch', icon: 'fa fa-layer-group'},
                                {value: 'row', name: 'Row', icon: 'fa fa-list'},
                                {value: 'form', name: 'Form', icon: 'fa fa-pen-square'},
                                {value: 'popup', name: 'Popup', icon: 'fa fa-comment-alt'}
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        location: 'after',
                        widget: 'dxButton',
                        options: {
                            icon: this.showFilterRow === 'No' ? 'fa fa-eye' : 'fa fa-eye-slash',
                            hint: this.showFilterRow === 'No' ? 'Show Filter Row' : 'Hide Filter Row',
                            width: 40,
                            onClick: (e) => {
                                console.dir(e);
                                this.showFilterRow = this.showFilterRow === 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        location: 'after',
                        widget: 'dxDropDownButton',
                        options: {
                            displayExpr: 'name',
                            keyExpr: 'value',
                            selectedItemKey: this.stateId,
                            width: 100,
                            stylingMode: 'outlined',
                            useSelectMode: true,
                            onSelectionChanged: (e) => {
                                this.stateId = e.item.value;
                                this.config  = this.setupColumns(e.item.query);
                                this.$emit('updateParcels');
                            },
                            items: this.states
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        location: 'after',
                        widget: 'dxButton',
                        options: {
                            icon: 'fa fa-bookmark',
                            hint: 'Save Table Filters',
                            onClick: (e) => {
                                this.newState     = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.updatedState));
                                this.popupVisible = true;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        location: 'after',
                        widget: 'dxButton',
                        options: {
                            icon: 'refresh',
                            width: 500,
                            hint: 'Refresh',
                            onClick: (e) => {
                                this.$emit('updateParcels');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    );
                },
```

I have tried increasing width of buttons, but it groups other control buttons in a combo box.

I want 5 buttons which fulfills business fucnctionalities in the toolbar and I dont want them to be in the same row as grid control buttons. Thats is why I want 2 line toolbar,first one is for grid controls, second one for business functionalities.

Is this at all possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

DevExtreme DataGrid uses the [Toolbar widget](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxToolbar/) in its toolbar area. The Toolbar widget does not support the multi-line functionality.